# How contacts content provider in android structures its data?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My task is to retreive name, phone, email, company and note from all contacts on android device. I have never worked with content providers before. I read content provider documentation, tutorials, saw code samples, but I'm still not quite sure: **does android stores information about name, phone, email, company and note in different tables?**

So do I have to query name, phone, email, company and note separately for each contact? 5 queries per contact * number of contact = most efficient way? Or do I have alternative with fewer number of queries? Why not to store all contacts and all contact fields in the same table so that it would be possible to get all data with single SELECT query (its analog in android content providers framework)?

So my main question again: do I have to make 5 queries per contact or there is more effient way?

Answer (score 0):

> does android stores information about name, phone, email, company and
>   note in different tables?

Almost. Name is stored in Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME.
phone and emails are in Data table but to interpret column names you need to use
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone class.

Update: The original article  I referred to was removed.
Here are the relevant links:

- [Android documentation overall](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html)
- [The columns reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html)

If you are interested in what goes on behind the curtain, google implemented their contact database (as of 4.2) so that phone, email are stored all in the same table called data. This table has columns like data1, data2 .... data15, which allows storing diverse data in that table as long as attribute of that data item do not exceed 15.
My guess it is for performance reasons - much faster to select all the data about one contact in one query() call.
Name is another story. It is stored in two tables, "raw_contacts"(column display_name) and also "data" (column "data1")

Comment: The main link is dead.

Comment: Correct, the link to the article is removed, it seems.